# How to convert timezones in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a sheet with two columns **Time Zone** and **Time** . I want to convert all these times to EST in a new column. Is there a way I can do this either with scripts app or native sheets formula?

[Image of Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpGcQ.png)

Comment: Do the time zones follow any specific format? Where were they retrieved from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add Sheet2 and paste in A1:

```
=UNIQUE(Sheet1!E2:E)
```

in B column set the diference:

[image]

then use formula:

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G="",,TEXT(G2:G+IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)/24), 
 "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm AM/PM")))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MlL_soeQ-LBoh2p0Fgky8EFiKNW4ZcTwNtA8R5W_YiM/edit#gid=0)